# SyntaxError: illegal character &#39; Passing a 2D List to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine, flask

I am using App Engine, Python, Flask, JavaScript/jQuery. I am getting this error:

> SyntaxError: illegal character '

Here is my view:

```
@login_required
def update_test(test_id):
    test = Test.get_by_id(test_id)
    return render_template('update_test.html', test=test)
```

Passing test to the template. test_data will contain a 2D list. Here is the model:

```
class Test(ndb.Model):
    """Test Models"""
    test_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    num_mc = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    num_or = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    num_students = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    correct_answers = ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True,indexed=False)
    pt_values = ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True,indexed=False)
    test_data = ndb.JsonProperty(repeated=True)
    added_by = ndb.UserProperty()
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

And finally, I need access to the list in JavaScript to build a HandsonTable grid:

```
 var num_mc = {{test.num_mc}};
    var num_or = {{test.num_or}};
    var total_questions = num_mc + num_or;
    var num_students = {{test.num_students}};
    console.log({{test.test_data}});
    var data = {{test.test_data}};
```

All variables pass through easily except for test_data. Please help me get access to a python list in JavaScript.

Comment: Is the Syntax Error in your javascript or python, the error you get should provide more information than you have supplied

Comment: SyntaxError: illegal character
console.log([[u&#39;Answers&#39;, u&#39;&#39;, u&#39;&#39;, u&#39;&#39;, u&#. The error is in the javascript. It comes up in Firefox Firebug.

Comment: So look at the json output of test_date and check that it is in fact valid json.

Comment: Worth making that edit an answer and marking it as accepted (that's considered acceptable in these parts :-) )

Comment: I can accept the answer in 2 days. Will do so. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to self-accept the answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out

In the view, use

```
new_data = json.dumps(test.test_data)
return render_template('update_test.html', test=test, data = new_data, bad_test = test.test_data)
```

Then add `|safe` in the template

```
console.log({{data|safe}});
```

Now I have access to the python list in javascript.